# Is there a python library that will allow me to piece together and export an mp3 file from a custom list of waveforms?

Tags: python, audio

Here's my problem. I have a huge number of waveform files of the same phrases in different languages and want to write a python script so that I can choose the phrase and language combinations and the script will build and export an mp3 file with the waveform phrases next to each other. The outputted file would for example, have the phrase 'nice to meet you' in English followed by it's equivalent in Japanese after a pause of 2 seconds, followed by the next item in the list with it's equivalent in Japanese. I want to know if there is a library that I need to do this or whether it can be written with the standard python library. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Can you please specify what have you tried as of now?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using dictionaries so, y = {"hello":"hola","etc"} And when one is called you can then convert it to the sound file. For example, if you are on a mac you can do

```
from os import system
system('say '+ hello)
```

This only works on a mac though.

I hope this helped however, you didn't mention what you have already tried, so I can't get anymore specific.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg 
http://ffmpeg.org/

Is a great solution for handling audio conversions with Python.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. However, I have found [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) to be easiest for audio manipulation. Especially for slicing and joining.

You can install using

`pip install pydub` #for 2.x
`pip3 install pydub` # for 3.x

Suppose your files are as below,

> your phrase in English = "nice_to_meet_you_eng.mp3"
>   And your phrase in Japanese = "nice_to_meet_you_jap.mp3"

You can use following example to join English phrase , followed by a 2 second delay and then Japanese phrase.

** This code is not tested **

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

#Create audio segments for audio files
nice_to_meet_you_eng = AudioSegment.from_mp3("nice_to_meet_you_eng.mp3")
nice_to_meet_you_jap = AudioSegment.from_mp3("nice_to_meet_you_jap.mp3")

#create two seconds of delay
two_second_of_silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=2000) # duration in millisec

#concatenate segments as per requirement
myphrase =nice_to_meet_you_eng + two_second_of_silence + nice_to_meet_you_jap 

#Export combined phrase
myphrase.export("myphrase.mp3", format="mp3")

#play combined phrase
play(myphrase)
```